# Bypass ssh key file permission check

Tags: ssh, permissions, private-key

I have an encrypted FAT volume (for compatibility) containing a private key file and other sensitive data.

I want to connect to my server through SSH using my private key, but of course, as FAT doesn't support file permission, it ignores my key saying its permissions are too open.

So currently I'm copying it somewhere else on my hard drive with 0600 permissions, using it and then securely erasing it, but it's a pain.

Is there a way to bypass permission check on this very ssh/scp command line ?

**Edit**: Precision: it was a TrueCrypt volume on OS X.

**On the solution:** The accepted answer below solved my problem (using a SSH key file located on a TrueCrypt volume with Mac OS X), but it is a workaround. *Looks like there is no way to "bypasssh key file permission check".*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to bypass the keyfile permission check with ssh or ssh-add (and you can't trick it with named pipe or such). Besides, you do not actually want to trick ssh, but just to be able to use your key files.

Indeed, TrueCrypt volume is supposed to keep your data private, so mounting the volumes as world-readable (default behaviour of TrueCrypt) is not really optimum. If you're using a FAT-formatted volume, you really should ajust the mount options, as Dan Carley suggested.

Although mount options aren't yet correctly supported by TrueCrypt for OS X (even if you launch TC using the command line interface and the mount options from the man page - already tried), OS X does support mount option defaults based on the volume name.

You need to know your user id (usually 501 if you are the first/only user of the computer). You can get it with "id -u".

Let' say you volume name is "PRIVATE" (volume names are in capitals), and your uid is 501, all you have to do is adding this line to /etc/fstab :

```
LABEL=PRIVATE none msdos -u=501,-m=700
```

You need to be root to create/edit this file (it is not present in default OSX install) :

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

Next time you mount the volume, it'll have permission 700 and owner id 501.

This also works with USB drives (which are usually formatted in FAT, too).

Comment: I couldn't get a FAT-formatted volume to get the right permissions with this method.  However, selecting "Mac OS Extended" and selecting the option to mount on other operating systems allows me to set the permissions with chmod.

Comment: This worked wonderfully. When I mount the secure volume I mount to specific point in my home directory. I found that I had to replace the value of 'none' with the explicit name of the mount point.

Comment: This works even when there is no `/etc/fstab` file on newer OS X. Just make a new `etc/fstab` file with the above

Answer (score 49):

Adding the key from stdin worked for me:

```
cat /path/to/id_rsa | ssh-add -k -
```

Comment: why does this have not one upvote? it works out of the box without mounting and you're using an ssh-agent anyway, didn't you?

Comment: works like a charm - should e the accepted answer

Comment: This got me in. Using WSL Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: In cygwin on Windows 10, I get `Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory` when trying this suggestion. Which is a bummer because file permissions are really screwed up in cygwin.

Answer (score 7):

As a crazy workaround, you could make a disk image of an ext2 volume containing your private key and mount it as a loop device, then use your ssh key from there.

Make a 1MB empty file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=diskimg bs=1024 count=1024
```

Format it ext2 (Press Y when it says it isn't a device):

```
mke2fs diskimg
```

Mount it somewhere (as root):

```
mount -t ext2 -o loop diskimg /my/path/to/diskimg
```

Now you have a tiny ext2 filesystem that you can set permissions on.  You could write a script to mount it and make sure those permissions have the right UID/GID based on whatever system you're on (since the UIDs may mismatch).  It also requires sudo/root access to work.

Comment: seems like there is no simpler option

Comment: that is so wrong - but very cool :)

Comment: @warren:  I did preface it with 'crazy'.  :-D

Answer (score 2):

What about adding `StrictModes no` to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (and the reload/restart sshd) ?

edit: oops, this option is server-side only :/

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, `ssh-agent` does not check for key permissions. So this might work:

```
[ -S "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || eval $(ssh-agent)
```

```
ssh-add path/to/id_rsa
```

Comment: FYI, This does not work.  `ssh-add` does check file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify your mount options (`umask`, `uid` and `gid`) to suit?

Comment: AFAIK No, it's a TrueCrypt volume, my only option is to mount it as read-only and ssh still complains it's 0777

Answer (score 0):

My recipe for dealing with Cygwin/Windows permissions and ssh keys in cygwin is as follows.

open first cygwin64 terminal, start `ssh-agent` there

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

change permissions of (any) key just before adding to the agent

```
chmod 400 my_key.pem
ssh-add my_key.pem
```

open future cygwin64 terminals out of this one to ensure they inherit the environment and have the `ssh-agent` with the key(s)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using a `vfat` formatted Truecrypt volume for the same compatibility reasons. But on Linux, using [`tcplay`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/tcplay.8.html) to mount it from a script.

In such a case, instead of editing `fstab`, the solution is to directly add the `umask=077` option to the `mount` command.

This is the relevant part of the script I use:

```sh
uid=$(id -u)
gid=$(id -g)

# ... losetup and tcplay commands ...

sudo mount -o nodev,nosuid,uid=$uid,gid=$gid,umask=077 /dev/mapper/$mnt_name $mnt_point
```